# How do I extend ui-router states in Angular 11?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, state

I have declared a state using ui-router in an Angular 2+ project using Ng2StateDeclaration.

```
export const myState:Ng2StateDeclaration{
  name:"myState",
  url:"mystate"
  component: "myComponent",
  params: {
    param1:"",
    param2:""
  }
}
```

How do I extend it to a new state without declaring it again and again.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the spread operator '...'

```
export const myState:Ng2StateDeclaration{
  name:"myState",
  url:"mystate"
  component: "myComponent",
  params: {
    param1:"",
    param2:""
  }
}

export const extendedState: Ng2StateDeclaration = {
  name: 'test',

  // Inherit properties from the base state
  ...myState,

  // Add or override properties specific to the extended state
  url: '/extendedstate',
  params: {
    ...myState.params,
    param3: 'blabla'
  }
};
```

Comment: This throws an error -> 
state with name "myState" already exists

Comment: are you creating a new state named myState? Because I used a your "myState" state as reference. Look at the updated code

Comment: No, The variable name as well as name parameter is diffrent.

Comment: can you show more of your code?